# OleDbCommand, two sequential "using"

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

With two sequential "using", will both connections be disposed when exiting from {}?

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly... Both `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` will be disposed at `}` line.

Comment: What 2 connections? I only see 1. But yes in this case both _objects_ will. Adding braces `{}` around blocks like `if` or `using` always makes it much clearer what will happen when, so is good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one *connection* there - and a command using the same connection. Both will be disposed.

This is effectively:

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    using(OleDbCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
    {
    } // command will be disposed here
} // con will be disposed here
```

Comment: Basically the same as `if(condition) Do();` and `if(condition) { Do(); }`